# avoiding illegal states in openai gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to make a gym environment for a simulation problem. In my gym environment, I have a set of illegal states which I don't want my agent to go into them. What is the easiest way to add such logic to my environment, should I use the wrapper classes? I didn't quite get them, I tried to extend the `MultiDiscrete` space with inheriting a class from it and override the `MulriDiscrete.sample` function to stop the environment from going into the illegal states, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where i need to make a gym environment which has a sort of pool in the center of grid world where i didn't want the agent to go.

So, I represented grid world as matrix and the pool had different depths which the agent can fall into, so the values at those locations had the negative value proportional to the depth of the puddle.

When training agents this negative reward prevented the agent to fall into the puddle.

The code for the above environment is [here](https://github.com/SaiVinay007/Reinforcement-Learning-CS6700/blob/master/assignments/programming/assignment_2/gym-pdw/gym_pdw/envs/pdw_env.py) and its usage is [here](https://github.com/SaiVinay007/Reinforcement-Learning-CS6700/blob/master/assignments/programming/assignment_2/pb2.ipynb)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I just want to eliminate the entire illegal states from the beginning not to learn them.

Comment: So for the agent to not get into a state which is illegal either the agent must already have intelligence to avoid such states or we hard code the space to constrain our observation space. Either way you are making the agent to avoid the illegal states, maybe you could solve your problem in step wise where in the first step you teach it to avoid obstacles then make it solve the main task. If you are aiming for an environment with some constraints then i guess you must define the environment that way (in the lines of how the original environment was made with a bounded observation space)

Comment: Yes, you are right but my question is about how to implement the hard code choice in the gym environment. I am sure that I want to hard code it not learn it.

Comment: I actually don't know what environment you are working with but previously i had a problem where the agent has to navigate between rooms. The agent shouldn't hit the walls so what i did was using the pattern of the wall i placed a particular value on those grid cells and when i get an action which puts me in that state i would re pick the action until i avoid hitting the wall. [Here](https://gist.github.com/SaiVinay007/7ead794b43a9c5345314465abdbfffb2) in line 154 see option_policy function decides where to move from the current position to move towards door and avoids colloding with wall